# Creating a popup box that pops ip after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, redirect, popup

I want to make a popup box, that when a user accesses this site: http://www.isicar.net/ it pops up after 2 seconds.  So, no clicking of any buttons invoiced to make the popup box appear

The popup box would act as a n advertisement, for users to sign up via this website: http://isicar.mine.nu/ so it would have to contain a button that redirects them to that URL and one that closes the popup box so they can return to the original page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After 2 or 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in [`ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) or [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) callback:

Use [**`setTimeout`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout):

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // Open the popup
}, 2000); // 2 seconds
```